# Drupal sub subthemes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am trying to do a set of secondary sub-themes based on a sub-theme (starterkit) from Zen.

Ideally:

- Parent Theme

  - Section 1
  - Section 2

    - Section 2A

I have my parent theme installed and working. For the section sub themes, I copied the parent theme, and renamed the appropriate files and folders, and changed the base theme in the .info to the name of the parent theme. Yet it is not inheriting certain things like template.php (section themes do not have them because they are supposed to be inherited I thought)- which means I don't receive body classes like my parent theme does.

What I really need to achieve is having specific style for these different sections, mainly text color and a background image change. Is this the simplest way to do it? I don't want to have one huge stylesheet so any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running D 6.20 ?  There was a fix for a subtheme inheritance issue in that update.

http://drupal.org/node/481142

Eric

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I am running 6.20. Pressflow.